# Redirect the output of a command to file without newline in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to redirect the command line output to the file without newline in windows.

for example,

```
   "%VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin\svnlook.exe" log -r 128 C:\Repositories > log.txt
```

The output of this command is just one line. Here i need to redirect the output to log.txt file without newline.

I'm able to echo the variable without newline to the file by following command,

```
  echo | set /p log=log_comments>log.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use the same trick and a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f %%L in ('"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin\svnlook.exe" log -r 128 C:\Repositories') do (
  <nul set /p "X=%%L" >log.txt
)
```